# how to find uppercase and smallCase using regex -re.findall in python

Tags: python, regex, findall, ignore-case

I have a code that search for expressions and highlight the matching word .

I need to  find the match regardless if its upper or lower cases i need the search to ignore the case sensitive .

code:

```
RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+x+'</b></u>'


    for counter , myLine in enumerate(filename):

        #added
        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
        thematch=re.sub(x,RepX,TextString)
        thematchFilt=re.findall(x,TextString,re.M|re.IGNORECASE)
```

example  the searched word : **charles**

the existing word is **Charles**

the system will not find the searched word unless i wrote **Charles**.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


text = "234422424"
text2 = "My text"


print( re.findall( r'^[A-Öa-ö\s]+', text)) # []
print( re.findall( r'^[A-Öa-ö\s]+', text2)) # ['My text']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) takes parameters as `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`.

```
import re
s = 'the existing word is Charles'
print(re.findall(r'charles', s, re.IGNORECASE))
# ['Charles']
```

[`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) ensures a case-insensitive match.

Comment: i tried re.IGNORECASE  BUT DID NOT find the requested word

Comment: no error but  the system must highlight the matching word so if i change  charles to Charles it will highlighted otherwise no word will be highlighted

Comment: Can you explain each parameter you used in your `findall`? What does each contain?

Comment: (x,TextString,re.M|re.IGNORECASE)....
x = user input 
TextString = the matching word in the file  or the string.

Comment: So `x` is some string and `TextString` is now 'charles', right?

Comment: x = charles 
textString = Charles

Comment: That should work. The problem is not related to re.findall, I guess. Because you have no error, I can't debug anything more. Try going through lines of your code.

Comment: what can be the problem? because i did not find any error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in  `thematch=re.sub(x,RepX,TextString)` it need also parameter flags. 
so it becomes `thematch=re.sub(x,RepX,TextString,flags= re.M|re.I)`